# Is there a category name for verbs like: think, assume, suppose, etc

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a category name for verbs like: think, assume, suppose, guess, believe, reckon, expect, hope, etc. I guess these verbs have in common that they can all introduce statements that describe thoughts.

Comment: A broader term that encompasses the words you list is _mental-state verbs_: https://www.thoughtco.com/mental-state-verb-1691306#:~:text=Common%20mental%2Dstate%20verbs%20in,forget%2C%20imagine%2C%20and%20believe.

Comment: All the verbs you've mentioned are *stative verbs*.

Comment: Might they be *putative* verbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the classification adopted by J D Apresjan in [*Principles of Systematic Lexicography*](https://www.euralex.org/elx_proceedings/Lexicography%20and%20Natural%20Language%20Processing/Juri%20D.%20Apresjan%20-%20Principles%20of%20Systematic%20Lexicography.pdf), there exist **two** types of verbs denoting mental states, with *guess* [correctly] and *think* being in different classes, relating to veridicality / modality:

> 3.1. Lexicographic types.
>
> I use this term to refer to a group of lexemes with a shared property
> or properties, not necessarily semantic, which are sensitive to the
> same linguistic rules and which should therefore be uniformly
> described in the dictionary. I shall exemplify this concept with the
> classes of factive and putative predicates. Both of them will be
> narrowed down to the subclasses of verbs denoting mental states (not
> processes or actions).
>
> 1. Following Vendler 1972, the label of "**factive**" is assigned to
>    verbs
>
> *know* /*understand,guess,remember,* ... [that P] and similar predicates which govern propositions denoting facts.  [P the proposition]
>
> All of them are decomposable into semantic structures with the sense
> 'to know'† at the bottom and presuppose the truth of the subordinate
> clause. That means that irrespective of whether the knowledge of P is
> asserted or denied, P always remains true. Such sentences as
>
> - *He knew that he was under police surveillance* and
> - *He didn't know that he was under police surveillance*
>
> are alike in asserting that he was under police surveillance [they entail that the surveillance was a reality]. [Note that this analysis focuses on 'know **that** ... ' , not 'know **whether** ... ' say. 'He knew / did not know whether ...' leaves the reader in the dark.]
>
> 2. The label of "**putative**" is assigned to verbs
>
> *think* / *believe, consider, find, hold, doubt*,... [that P] and similar predicates which denote opinions. Opinions, unlike knowledge,
> are not necessarily true. In other words, it cannot be deduced either
> from the sentence
>
> - *He thought that he was under police surveillance*, or from the sentence
> - *He didn't think that he was under police surveillance*
>
> whether he was in fact under surveillance or not.
>
> .....................
>
> † In accordance with the treatment of knowledge in theoretical studies
> and the lexicographic description of the verb to know in major
> dictionaries I distinguish propositional knowledge (I know that he has
> come) from knowledge-acquaintance (Do you know Sam?), knowledge
> familiarity (He knows French literature very well) and some other
> types of knowledge. All these uses of to know are considered to
> represent different lexical meanings (different senses, different
> lexemes) of the verb. In this article only propositional knowledge is
> at issue.
>
> ...........
>
> ‡ After P. Kiparsky and C. Kiparsky 1971: 345 where the notion of
> factivity was first introduced: prototypical factive predicates are
> exemplified with a different series of words – adjectives like (It's)
> significant / odd, tragic, exciting [that P], and verbs like (It)
> suffices / amuses [me], bothers [me] [that P]. I side with Z. Vendler
> in ranking to know as a prototypical factive predicate.

[reformatted & amended]

[Note that 'I'm guessing that you're from Wyoming' shows a putative usage of 'guess': bystanders do not know the validity of this guess from the words spoken.]